# HTML5 video element not loading on iPhone/iPad

Tags: iphone, html, ipad, video, html5-video

This is a repeat question, but I haven't been able to find a solution that works for me. I can't seem to figure out why my `<video>` element is not loading on iPhone or iPad.

Here is my HTML code:

```
<div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
<video id="movie" preload controls autobuffer>
<source src="/digital-portfolio/video/client.mp4" type="video/mp4">
<source src="/digital-portfolio/video/client.webm" type="video/webm">
<source src="/digital-portfolio/video/client.ogv" type="video/ogg">
</video>
</div>
```

The video plays fine in Google Chrome but has issues displaying on an iPhone or iPad. Additionally, I have added the following to my `.htaccess` file:

```
# Video
AddType video/mp4                                   mp4 m4v f4v f4p
AddType video/ogg                                   ogv
AddType video/webm                                  webm
AddType video/x-flv                                 flv
```

From all of the resources I've read, I should have covered my bases well to play this `<video>` element on most browsers/devices but it is still not working. Here is an image of my video on an iPhone:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a few possibilities.

The first one to try is adding the `Accept-Ranges: bytes` HTTP response header as shown here [Safari Web Content Guide: Configuring Your Server](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/CreatingVideoforSafarioniPhone/CreatingVideoforSafarioniPhone.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006514-SW6)

If that doesn't work then it's possible that you may need to reencode the video with some different encoding flags. I've had success with ffmpeg and parameters like this:

```
ffmpeg -i %1 -pass 1 -vcodec libx264 -preset slow -profile:v baseline   -b:v 2000k -b:a 128k -r 25 -g 50 -vf setfield=1 -f mp4 -threads 0 -y %1-hq.mp4
ffmpeg -i %1 -pass 2 -vcodec libx264 -preset slow -profile:v baseline   -b:v 2000k -b:a 128k -r 25 -g 50 -vf setfield=1 -f mp4 -threads 0 -y %1-hq.mp4
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Where would I add the `Accept-Ranges: bytes`?

Comment: If you're using Apache as your web server then you would put `Header set Accept-Ranges bytes` in your httpd.conf or relevant vhost file.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I will try that.